# frama-c metrics output to file for metrics-by-function

Tags: frama-c

I am trying to output the metrics results to a file.
I know that I can call `-metrics-output`, and output the global metrics analysis to a file, but I am also trying to get the results of each function.

Calling:

```
frama-c -metrics -metrics-output test.txt -metrics-by-function example.c
```

or:

```
frama-c -metrics -metrics-by-function -metrics-output test.txt example.c
```

Just results in a file with the global metrics.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have reviewed the code of the plugin, and it seems that per-function output is available for the console and `.html` outputs only, not for the `.txt` one. So you can either

1. drop `-metrics-output test.txt` entirely, and pipe the output of Frama-C to a file. You get a different sub-section for each function
2. use `-metrics-output test.html`. The per-function information is available as an html array.

As an aside, the order of options is not significant in Frama-C. The `-then` operator can be used for sequencing if needs be. Hence, your two commands are equivalent.

Comment: Much appreciated :) I will probably have to pipe it and parse it by reading the piped file